# how wait thread with parameters and doesn't freeze main thread

Tags: c#

I write code, which call thread with parameters. But my program is  windows forms. So how change code, that wait thread, and that GUI of my program not freeze?

```
var t=new Thread(()=>SomeMethod(SomeParameter));
t.Start();
//t.Wait?
```

Comment: `var resultOfSomeMethod = await Task.Run(()=>SomeMethod(SomeParameter));`

Comment: There is no point whatsoever in using a thread if you want to wait for it.  Just call *SomeMethod()* directly.  Of course your UI will still freeze, no difference.  The point is not wait for it so your UI thread can continue to do its normal duties.  Like responding to input and painting the windows.

Comment: You don't.  You need to not wait for the thread to complete.  That's the whole point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have `await` available, the simplest solution is to use a `BackgroundWorker`:

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

bw.DoWork += (sender, args) => {
    // do your lengthy stuff here -- this will happen in a separate thread
    ...
}

bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => {
    if (args.Error != null)  // if an exception occurred during DoWork,
        MessageBox.Show(args.Error.ToString());  // do your error handling here

    // Put here the stuff you wanted to put after `t.Wait`
    ...
}

bw.RunWorkerAsync(); // start the background worker
```

`RunWorkerCompleted` runs in the UI thread, so you will be able to update your UI there (as opposed to stuff happening in `DoWork`).